# Open a existing app from own app ios

Tags: ios, app-store

When I use the below code to check if an app is installed on my device it does the job, I checks, if not installed it will install, so far so good.
Problem however is when the app is installed I want to open the app directly, what happens now is that the link opens the app store (as expected) but I have to manually push the open button and I was wondering is this can be done without having to push the open button.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                   @"https://itunes.apple.com/xxx"]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/xxx"]];    }

else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"App not installed on Device"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Open link", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: After another read I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking how to launch an app that is already installed or are you asking how to launch an app after your launch the app store and the user then installs the app?

Comment: @rmaddy I'm certain he is talking about the case where the app is already installed because then in the app store the button in the top right corner would read "Open" (instead of "Free" or "$2.99").

Comment: @rmaddy Like Justin Moser explained, that is the case when the app is installed I still have to click on open and I would like this to be automated. Answer below works fine for own developed apps not sure how it works with third party apps though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app you want to open has defined a [custom scheme](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html), you can open it directly by calling `openURL:` with a URL that starts with that scheme. In your code it would look like:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                   @"theAppsCustomScheme://xxx"]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"theAppsCustomScheme://xxx"]];    
}
else
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                               @"https://itunes.apple.com/xxx"]])
    {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/xxx"]];    
    }
    else
    {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The AppStore cannot be launched, please install the app manually"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Open link", nil];
         [alert show];
    }
}
```

you can check wether the app has a custom scheme at its `.plist` file. It must have a  "URL Types"/"URL schemes"[0] item.

Comment: I've never done custom scheme stuff before but if x-callback-url exists then I'm confident this answer would work.

Comment: @simpleBob thanks that works perfect with my own developed apps, however is there a way to get the custom scheme from a third party app ?

Comment: @ECKO unfortunately, no there isn't. Since you cannot scan apps outside of your app's sandbox. However, there are some websites that contain a list of known schemes (for example [this wiki](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) or [this website](http://handleopenurl.com/))